# How to prove this inequality involving ratio of sums?

Tags: inequality

Let $K=\{1,\ldots,k\}$ be a set of $k$ jobs. Each job $j\in K$ has a positive weight $w_j$ and a positive profit $p_j$. Let $\ell^*$ be the job such that:

$$\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell^*}w_j}{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell^*}p_j}=\max\limits_{1\leq\ell\leq k}\left(\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell}w_j}{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell}p_j}\right).$$

The ratio on the left-hand side is called the $\rho$-factor of $K$, denoted $\rho(K)$. Job $\ell^*$ is referred to as the job that determines the $\rho$-factor of $K$.

**Claim:** If $\ell^*$ is the job that determines the $\rho$-factor of $K$, then for any $u\in\{1,\ldots,\ell^*-1\}$, we have:
$$\dfrac{w_{u+1}+w_{u+2}+\ldots+w_{\ell^*}}{p_{u+1}+p_{u+2}+\ldots+p_{\ell^*}}>\dfrac{w_{1}+w_{2}+\ldots+w_{u}}{p_{1}+p_{2}+\ldots+p_{u}}.$$

How can I prove this claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the fact:
if   $\dfrac {a}{b}\leq\dfrac {c}{d}$ then $\dfrac {a+c}{b+d}\leq\dfrac {c}{d}$

if  $\dfrac{w_{u+1}+w_{u+2}+\ldots+w_{\ell^*}}{p_{u+1}+p_{u+2}+\ldots+p_{\ell^*}}\leq\dfrac{w_{1}+w_{2}+\ldots+w_{u}}{p_{1}+p_{2}+\ldots+p_{u}}$
then,

$\dfrac{w_{1}+w_{2}+\ldots+w_{\ell^*}}{p_{1}+p_{2}+\ldots+p_{\ell^*}}\leq\dfrac{w_{1}+w_{2}+\ldots+w_{u}}{p_{1}+p_{2}+\ldots+p_{u}}$

But this contradicts with the maximality  of $\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell^*}w_j}{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell^*}p_j}$

Actually, equality case might not be thought as a contradiction. However, if we chose ${\ell^*}$ such that ${\ell^*}$ is minimum that satisfies $\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell^*}w_j}{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell^*}p_j}=\max\limits_{1\leq\ell\leq k}\left(\dfrac{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell}w_j}{\sum_{j=1}^{\ell}p_j}\right)$ ,then it's certainly a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. But we want to prove the fact, how would you use it?

Comment: When we had the contradiction, it meant we have proved that inequality is satisfied in other direction which is what we want. Am I wrong?

Comment: But why did you use the fact in your first line?

Comment: Because if  $\dfrac{w_{u+1}+w_{u+2}+\ldots+w_{\ell^*}}{p_{u+1}+p_{u+2}+\ldots+p_{\ell^*}}\leq\dfrac{w_{1}+w_{2}+\ldots+w_{u}}{p_{1}+p_{2}+\ldots+p_{u}}$ were true, then $\dfrac{w_{1}+w_{2}+\ldots+w_{u+1}+w_{u+2}+\ldots+w_{\ell^*}}{p_{1}+p_{2}+\ldots+p_{u+1}+p_{u+2}+\ldots+p_{\ell^*}}\leq\dfrac{w_{1}+w_{2}+\ldots+w_{u}}{p_{1}+p_{2}+\ldots+p_{u}}$

Comment: You said, if   $\dfrac {a}{b}\leq\dfrac {c}{d}$, then $\dfrac {a+c}{b+d}\leq\dfrac {c}{d}$. I don't understand why this is true.

Comment: okey, $\dfrac {a}{b}\leq\dfrac {c}{d}$ iff $ad \leq bc$ iff $ad+dc \leq bc+dc$ iff $\dfrac {a+c}{b+d}\leq\dfrac {c}{d}$

Comment: Great. Thank you again.